# How to have the same scale for two maps?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, scale

I'm using QGIS 2.8.1. I have one raster map with rainfall data with 1:3 scale when zoomed to layer.

[image: Raster map(Scale highlighted in yellow)]

There's another vector map with points which in scale 1:221,691 when zoomed to layer.

[image: Vector map(Scale highlighted in yellow)]

Both are having the same CRS which is WGS 84/UTM zone 44N EPSG:32644.
I want to use "Add grid values to points function" under Raster-Vector operations in the processing toolbox. But grid values appear as null for the points in the output attribute table. I think this because the scales are different. How can I solve this?

Comment: make sure the data has the same coordinate system and that they share zones. In the image you can see that they do not share the same zone

Comment: Rainfall is probably in epsg:4326 not UTM

Comment: But if I change the CRS of rainfall map I can't get the grid values for the points since the two maps will then have different CRSs. Is there a way to get the grid values for maps having different CRSs?

Comment: Reproject one of them, so both have the same CRS. Do NOT simply set the CRS, this doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Erik thank you. Reprojecting the map worked :)